# Sizing to fit rows and columns in a QTableView is very slow

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtableview, qt4.7

I've got a QTableView with a custom model, and it works fine. However, when I start the program, I want the rows and columns to be sized to fit because by default they take up too much space. I should note that my table has 65k rows (only 3 columns), and they're always the same. The following code works fine, but is very slow.

memorListView is a QTableView. Prior to this line, I `setModel` to my custom model

```
memoryListView->resizeRowsToContents();
memoryListView->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

Like I mentioned, this does exactly what I need, but it takes about 8 seconds to run. I presume it's because all the data needs to be pulled out of the model, when the view is otherwise happy to be lazy about requesting it.

I could set the row and column size manually, which is my current workaround, but this is a cross-platform app and I'd like to not have to worry about different widgets, text sizes, DPIs, etc causing a problem. I could autosize *one* row and then set the rest to that row's size, which would be correct but seems very hacky.

I'm hoping that I'm just doing this naively, and there's some option I can toggle that'll make it faster. I know all rows and columns will be the same size; can I tell it to use that hint somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply measure the width of the text using `QFontMetrics`, then set the column width to it. Something like that should work:

```
QFontMetrics fontMetrics(yourWidget->font());
int columnWidth = fontMetrics.width("some text");
```

Comment: Hmm I'll give that a shot. It looks promising.